# Select distinct count on field that has two different values within another field

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a table with no primary key. It hold email addresses that have a flag field marked as either 'available' or 'unavailable'.

What I'm trying to do is count distinct email addresses that have only the 'available' flag, and not count distinct email addresses which may have a row with the 'available' and 'unavailable' flags.

Should I place the table into another table and start deleting with different queries?

Example: since test@gmail.com has two records, it will still be a distinct email address; however, I do not want to count this because it has both 'available' and 'unavailable' flags.

Email             Flag
test@gmail.com    available
test@gmail.com    unavailable

Thank you for any help!

Josh

Comment: but the field can only set to available OR unavailable, not both ?

Comment: SELECT email_id FROM my_table where flag = 'available'
MINUS
SELECT email_id FROM my_table where flag != 'unavailable';

Comment: @Begueradj, it's a table with no primary key, means repeated records

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
select email
from table t
group by email
having sum(case when flag = 'unavailable' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when flag = 'available' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you want a count of them, just use this as a subquery and put `select count(*) from` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN av = 1 AND unav = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS totalavailableemails  
FROM
(
    SELECT email, MAX(CASE WHEN  av = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS av, MAX(CASE WHEN  unav = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unav
    FROM emails
    GROUP BY email
) AS table1
```

where `av` is the available flag and `unav` is unavailable flag

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64b98/1)